# como el usuario puede agregar varios datos con input() y convertirlos en un lista como por ejemplo que salga así [x, b, c]

Tags: python-3.x, lista, funciones, entrada, datos

quiero sacar la media de la clase introduciendo varios datos y que lo haga una lista por ejemplo introduzco 15 16 17 18 y que salga en una lista asi: [15, 16, 17, 18]

```
def puntuacion(clase):
    return sum(clase) / len(clase)

clase = ??

media = puntuacion(clase)
print(f"La puntuación de esta clase es:{media}")
```

Comment: Bienvenido Lucas David Laurente Rojas a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando así, tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas.

Answer (score 1):

La solución es pedir primero los puntajes separados por espacios y usar `split` para convertilos en una lista.

```
lista = input("Ingrese los puntajes separados por espacios ").split()
```

En esta lista los puntajes vienen como cadenas; debo convertirlos a enteros para poder calcular con ellos. Para eso uso comprensión de listas:

```
puntajes = [int(x) for x in lista]
```

Con eso tengo una lista de puntajes como enteros.

#### Demo

```
def puntuacion(clase):
    return sum(clase) / len(clase)

lista = input("Ingrese los puntajes separados por espacios ").split()
puntajes = [int(x) for x in lista]

media = puntuacion(puntajes)
print(f"La puntuación de esta clase es:{media}")
```

produce:

```
Ingrese los puntajes separados por espacios 10 20 10
La puntuación de esta clase es:13.333333333333334

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Hola gracias por responder y creo que ya le halle una solución pero mira mi código para verificar si es entendible:

```
def puntuacion(clase):
    return sum(clase) / len(clase)

Notas_de_alumnos = []

lista = int(input("Escribe el numero de alumnos de la clase: " ))
for i in range(lista):
    punt_individual = int(input("Escriba la puntuacion de un alumno: "))
    Notas_de_alumnos.append(punt_individual)

media = puntuacion(Notas_de_alumnos)
print(f"La puntuación de esta clase es:{media}")
```